# Add jar to mono for android project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

How do I add jar files to my Mono for Android project in Visual Studio (2010) so that I can use them via [JNIEnv](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/api_design#Java_Native_Interface_Support)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add add you jar as a file in your project, and then set the 'Build Action' in the properties window to 'AndroidJavaLibrary' - and that's it.

The hard bit is the JNIEnv part!

Comment: But there is a lekker tool coming with the next few releases round about 4.2 of mono for android. It should automate it. Keep watching.

Comment: FYI, I've created a blog post about this topic: http://manski.net/2012/03/30/accessing-java-classes-from-mono-for-android-via-jni/